# Working with concrete type of a base parameter passed in a strategy method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, oop, casting

I ran at a major architectural problem.

**CONTEXT**

I'm trying to build an ASP.NET Core microservice application that implements the strategy pattern.
The application communicates with other microservices.

I have a main entity that aggregates all the information I need to work with, let's call it "MainContext". The goal is that this entiy is loaded and built only one time (as we need to get that information from other microservices) and then is processed throughout the whole application.

```
public class MainContext
{
    public DeterminerAttribute Attribute {get; set; }

    public OtherContextA       ContextA { get; set; }

    public OtherContextB       ContextB { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the MainContext aggregates other contexts. These '*OtherContexts*' are base classes that have their own child classes. They are somehow different and have different types and quantities of fields.

The application builds the MainContext in one separate place. The process looks something like this:

1. We get a specific attribute from other microservice and use this attribute as a determiner in a switch expression. The attribute is also saved in MainContext.
2. In switch expression we load specific implementations of OtherContextA and OtherContextB classes and wrap them up in their base classes. This step is important, as I don't want to ask for information that I don't need from other services.
3. The method returns MainContext with all information loaded, ready to use.

Then, I use strategy pattern, because different contexts require different treatment.

**THE PROBLEM**

The strategies have the same interface, and thus should implement the same methods that have the same signature. In my case, there is only one method, that looks something like this:

```
public class SomeStrategyToProcessContext : StrategyInterface
{
    public async Task ProcessContext(MainContext mainContext, ...);
}
```

Now, in strategies I want to work with concrete implementations of Contexts. It makes sense as I KNOW, as a programmer who made that mess, that the strategies to be used are chosen based on the same attribute that I used to load contexts and therefore should work with the concrete implementations, as I need data stored in them. But this:

`var concreteContext = (OtherConcreteContextA) mainContex.ContextA`

is considered a bad pratice, AFAIK.

Obviously, base classes have only base, unspecific data. In strategy classes, I want to provide access only to the NEEDED data, no more, no less.

My quistion is: is there any safe and sustainable way of implementing this witin OOP (or other) paradigm? I want to avoid the casting, as it breaks the abstraction and contradics every programming principle I've learned about. Any advice, even if it's toxic or/and suggests to change the whole architecture is as good as gold. Thanks!

Comment: check out the visitor pattern

Comment: @Moho It oddly came to my mind right before you wrote your comment. Now I'm more convinced that it will solve my problem, thanks!